# Can I hook up two baseboard heaters on a 30 amp double pole breaker with #12 wire?

Tags: electric-heat

I want to run 2 baseboard heaters on a double pole 30 amp breaker with 12/2 wire. Is that ok?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: What are the wattage ratings on the heaters involved? What make and model is your breaker panel?

Answer (score 6):

No!  12/2 wire is NOT suitable for a 30 A circuit.

While there are other considerations, you will need to use a MINIMUM of 10 AWG Cu wire for a 30A circuit.

Beyond that, whether 30A is enough for your two heaters cannot be answered because that depends on the current requirements for the heaters.

Answer (score 4):

Do the space heaters total **less than** 3840 watts?  Then just change the 240V breaker to 20A, done.

Can't run 12 AWG wire off a 30A breaker, but you probably don't need to.  If you're going "Oh, gosh, I already own a 30A breaker", **20A breakers cost ten bucks**.

If you're dealing with an obscure panel like Pushmatic where 20A breakers are not ten bucks, then stay with 30A but run 10 AWG wire.

Answer (score 2):

No, #12 wire is limited to a maximum of 20A overcurrent protection by NEC 240.4(D)(4).

Generally fixed electric space heating is required to be treated as a continuous load by 424.3(B), so 210.20(A) limits a 20A space heating breaker to 16A, or #10 wire on a 30A breaker to 24A.